# How to get specific result from a sql table

Tags: sql

From the following data-script I want to get as a select result only the last combination ('1111111113', 'viber'). I want to search the temp table and try to find numbers that have been used only with one type (for my example only 'viber').

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(number NVARCHAR(MAX),
 [type] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('1111111111', 'tel' ),
('1111111111', 'tel' ),
('1111111111', 'viber' ),
('1111111111', 'viber' ),
('1111111111', 'tel2' ),
('1111111111', 'tel2' ),
('1111111112', 'tel' ),
('1111111112', 'tel' ),
('1111111112', 'tel2' ),
('1111111112', 'tel2' ),
('1111111113', 'viber' ),
('1111111113', 'viber' );
```

My first thought was the following select query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       *
FROM #temp
WHERE [type] = 'viber'
      AND number NOT IN
(
    SELECT number
    FROM #temp
    WHERE [type] <> 'viber'
);
```

But I'm trying to find if there is an other way maybe more efficient than this. My table is going to hav millions of data in it so I need to be sure that the result of my search wiil be fast enough.

Thanks in advance.

PS. This is my first time posting something on stackoverflow after years of reading so please excuse me If i did something the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

**1st option:**

```
select distinct t1.number, t1.type
from #temp t1
where t1.number not in (select t2.number 
                        from #temp t2
                        where t2.type <> t1.type)
```

I am not sure this is the best way but you can test it by yourself.

**2nd option** (should be faster):

```
select distinct t1.number, t1.type
from #temp t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from #temp t2
                  where t1.type <> t2.type
                        and t1.number = t2.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is about right, I prefer to group rather than use distinct.

```
SELECT 
number,
type
FROM #temp
WHERE [type] = 'viber'
      AND number NOT IN
(
    SELECT number
    FROM #temp
    WHERE [type] <> 'viber'
    group by number
)
group  by 
number, type
```

Answer (score 0):

Given proper indexes, this will be faster than the sub-selects provided in the other answers in my experience.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       t1.*
FROM #temp t1
LEFT JOIN #temp t2 ON t1.type<>t2.type
    AND t1.number=t2.number
WHERE t2.type IS NULL
```